# Having trouble summing while loop values with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk

I'm trying to get the sum, `36962`, to echo with `$TOTAL` at the end of the script, but I cannot get it to work. Any advice? This is for a school project and I am pretty rusty with Bash.

```
TOTAL=0
while read p; do
    awk '{ if ($1 > 100 ) print TOTAL+=$1}'
    echo $TOTAL
done < ipuniq.txt
```

- 6578
- 6723
- 32735
- 36962
- ECHOS -> 0

Comment: bash and awk are 2 completely separate, independent tools and you wouldn't write a loop using bash to call awk one line at a time, you'd just do it all in awk (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). Post some concise, testable sample input and expected output if you'd like help.

Comment: Thank you for educating me on the differences.between awk and bash. Had no clue about that.

Comment: You can do this with awk only. `awk '$1 > 100 { sum+=$1 } END { print sum }'`  Awk is perfectly suited for these tasks

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  People answering the question will almost always use that input to actually test their answer and since you are asking people for a favor it's more polite to allow them to copy and paste rather than have to retype from an image.  You can select a block of text and press _ctrl_ + _k_ to make a code block or surround it with ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TOTAL` variable is a shell variable and therefore `awk` won't know about it. In your `awk` command the `TOTAL` variable is unset in each iteration so it's being reset with a single value each time and then printed.

Additionally, it seems pointless to use `awk` in a loop like this.

`awk` can perform this operation by itself with the following 1 liner:

```
awk '$1 > 100 { total+=$1 } END { print total }' ipuniq.txt
```

No loops or other commands needed.

---

However, if your assignment requires you use bash/shell you could do:

```
total=0
while read -r p _; do
    ((p>100)) && total=$((total+p))
done < ipuniq.txt
echo "$total"
```

This will use a shell arithmetic expression to check if the value of `p` is greater than 100, if so it will add it to `total`.

Additionally note: I have added the `-r` option to your `read` command as this will print backslashes literally (likely unnecessary for your use case but I prefer to use `-r` at all times unless I specifically have a reason not to.)

I have also added the `_` parameter name, this will prevent `p` from being set to an undesirable input.  `read` will assign all leftover words to the last parameter, so in your case say your file contains numbers and IPs like:

```
1 10.10.10.10
2 10.10.10.11
```

Without a parameter to catch the cruft, `p` would be set to:

```
p='1 10.10.10.10'
```

then:

```
p='2 10.10.10.11'
```

Comment: I put the echo "$total" outside of the loop and it worked great! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @JoshuaTrimm: ah, I wasn't sure what your intent was and thought you wanted to print the current total on each iteration.  I have updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: @JoshuaTrimm wrt `I put the echo "$total" outside of the loop and it worked great!` - you shouldn't be doing that at all, you should be using the awk-only script.

Comment: How do I get the IP address with the loop? I know how to get the number and add the total. But I need to the ip address with another list of ips....